# A stable/LTS Linux distro (Fedora,openSUSE,Ubuntu,Debian) with simple VirtualBox 5+ installation?

Tags: virtualbox, distribution-choice

I have lost too much having Windows as a host OS, especially after upgrading to 10. My processor is AMD64 [(specs)](http://www.flixfacts.co.uk/view/mediaplayer/?l=us&demo=0&d=5698&f=amd-fxpib&p=204160&g=&rmpn=&txt=&pm=fd4350frhkbox&cp=no&btg=LN5&t=fl&),

```
AMD Virtualization™ (AMD-V™) Technology with IOMMU

Silicon feature-set enhancements for improved performance, reliability and security of existing and future virtualization environments by allowing virtualized apps direct, rapid access to their allocated memory
IOMMU is an extension to AMD64 architecture to support address translation and access protection on DMA transfers
    Security for user-level application and virtual machine guest OS
        Address translation and access control
        Device isolation
        Device assignment in virtualized systems
        Security and trusted boot support
        Unified interrupt manageme
```

I am a Java, C, (intermediate), Cython 3.x,node.JS, .NET programmer.

I am asking for a relatively new, stable distro of Linux which takes advantage of having amd64 hardware, and where VirtualBox is an easy installation process. I'm starting at the [VirtualBox 5.0 Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0) as a reference. I plan to run Windows 8.1, and possibly Windows 10 as a guest OS.

*Note: I haven't had success with openSUSE 13.2, using VirtualBox or VMWare 12, Xen, or KDE/QEMU*

Thanks

Comment: What is not simple about the VirtualBox install for OpenSUSE? Why do you need the bleeding edge VirtualBox? It is not going to affect your programming in a Windows VM in any noticeable way

Comment: Maybe it is simple to you, but for me, I assign the installation .iso as 1st in the boot order, boot the OS (tried 8.1 x64 and 10 x64 .ISOs) but it never launches into setup. Anyway, after enough time I just used Windows 10 Pro as my host OS, with careful attention to backups. Hyper-V is installed by default - and its support for every Linux OS I've tried, can't even handle bidirectional copy-paste. I'll see if a VirtualBox installation of archlinux or ubuntu server, fedora, ... will do better than hyper-V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run [Archlinux](https://www.archlinux.org/) and I have VirtualBox. It has the advantage to be a rolling release so you don't have the problem to upgrade to a new version every 6 to 12 months, and you always get the latest software a few days after they are released by the upstream.

Also, if you are relatively new using Linux, you can try [ArchBang](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), an out of the box and easy to use version of ArchLinux.

Also you might be interested in Fedora, Ubuntu or Linux Mint which also provide VirtualBox 5 and are more ready to use and user friendly.

Also, you might be interested in [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM) with which you can easily assign devices for each VM, being able to use your GPU directly in Windows with Windows driver. The difference is that KVM works at a lower level, directly in the kernel, so you have very low overhead when running a virtual machine. Xen is also similar (I saw that you tried it), but with a little more overhead. The drawback is that you can't run other architecture than the one supported by your hardware, unlike VirtualBox and Qemu.

Comment: Just tried VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.0.3 LTS, and ran into a problem I had with openSUSE 13.2, where the Windows guest failed to boot from its .iso because of some error I'd get about the virtualbox kernel failing to run the virtualbox daemon; something like that.  I like the KVM idea, last time I tried KVM on openSUSE 13.2, but it required a server to be running, which disconnected at any time, like in the middle of Windows guest installation.

Comment: You need to start the VirtualBox drivers:
`sudo modprobe vboxdrv`
`sudo modprobe vboxnetflt`
̀`sudo modprobe vboxnetadp`

Answer (score 0):

Try Linux Mint. To install VirtualBox `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

I assume that you are going to do .Net development on the virtual machine, if that is the case, I recommend to have a dual-boot setup, so you can use all your machine performance.

Comment: No vote. Probably is planning to snapshot .vhd,  .vmdk instances of Windows. Just wondering, why Mint?

Comment: @T.Webster Probably. I said Mint because I never had problem with VirtualBox (or VMware) on it.